# Outlet works on simulator, but crashes on device

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, interface-builder

I have a very simple view with a button and a label. In XCode's Interface Builder I ctrl-dragged to get a reference to the UIButton and called it `btnPlay`. In my view controller I have this code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    // On my phone this line causes a crash:
    Console.WriteLine("Button title: {0}", btnPlay.CurrentTitle);
}
```

When I run the app in the iPhone Simulator (3.5" Retina / iOS 7.0) all is well. Inspecting btnPlay at a breakpoint shows it as a `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton` object.

When I run the app on my iPhone 5C (iOS 7) `btnPlay` shows up as a `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView` object which has no `CurrentTitle` property and so crashes the app.

What can be the cause of this?

**More info**:

- A [stack trace from the device log crash
  report](https://gist.github.com/JannieT/8234891)
- My setup: Xamarin Studio V 4.2.2 (build 2) * Mono 3.2.5 * Xcode 5.0.2 (3335.32) * Xamarin.iOS Version: 7.0.4.209 (Indie Edition) * Build date: 2013-11-11 16:04:00-0500
- In my view's .designer.cs class the property is of type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton`
- In the .xib file it is a `<button>`
- Deleting the app from the phone and running a clean build doesn't solve the issue
- I can't reproduce the behaviour in a simple app with just one view and one button, so I'm asking for clues where to start looking for the problem

Comment: May I ask why you are using IB and not Xamarin's UI designer which frees you from all these nasty Outlet stuff? http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/

Comment: @Krumelur: the XS designer only works with storyboards

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix True, but not really a reason I'd say.

Comment: @Krumelur I'm on the stable release channel, waiting patiently for Xamarin's storyboard designer. As a workaround I am going XIB-less, but I am aiming for a solution where I can work together with a talented designer in our team.

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashes the app"? Can you show the stack trace? What's in your View.designer.cs class as the connected control - a UIView or a UIButton? Could it be that your device still has partially old code on it (maybe an issue with incremental builds enabled) - delete the app from the device, clean the solution, rebuild and redeploy. If the issue can be reproduced, you should file a bug at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Thanks @Krumelur - please see the updated info in my question.

Comment: The crash report indicates that this is not something obvious, so I'd file a bug report here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a test case we can use to reproduce the crash.